# ListView in Fragment not getting displayed

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have this problem about my listview not getting displayed in my fragment. I have checked other related problems on StackOverflow and i haven't gotten the answer. The other fragments work well except this fragment that is meant to display the listview. Below is the code. Fragment xml only contains a listview.

```
    public class FeaturedIsh extends Fragment {
        ListView listview;

        String title[] ={"Quote of the week","Devotional","News","Events"};
        Integer titleImage[] = {R.drawable.user,R.drawable.user,R.drawable.user,R.drawable.user};
        String content[] = {"The more you do, the more you are able to do, the less you do, the less you are able to do","Today's topic : Careful for nothing", "Bukola Babies won again","Two weddings this Saturday"};

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            String title[] = {"Quote of the week","Devotional","News","Events"};
            Integer titleImage[] = {R.drawable.user,R.drawable.user,R.drawable.user,R.drawable.user};
            String content[] = {"The more you do, the more you are able to do, the less you do, the less you are able to do","Today's topic : Careful for nothing", "Bukola Babies won again","Two weddings this Saturday"};

            Log.d("yo", "onCreate worked");

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featuredish, container, false);
            listview = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.feat_list_view);
            Log.d("yo","inflater true");
            FeaturedAdapterListNav Falnav = new FeaturedAdapterListNav(getActivity(), title, titleImage, content);
            Log.d("yo","Adapter worked");
            listview.setAdapter(Falnav);
            Log.d("yo", "Adapter set");
            return v;
        }
    }

Here is my adapter code

package com.example.cozasocial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

/**
 * Created by SamuelAgbede on 5/12/2015.
 */
public class FeaturedAdapterListNav extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Activity context;
    String[] title;
    Integer[] titleImage;
    String[] content;

    public FeaturedAdapterListNav(Activity context, String[] title, Integer[] titleImage, String[] content) {
        super(context, R.layout.featured_each_row);

        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.titleImage = titleImage;
        this.content = content;


    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_each_row, null, true);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.image_featured);
        TextView contents = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.content);
        TextView headings = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.heading);

        image.setImageResource(titleImage[position]);
        contents.setText(content[position]);
        headings.setText(title[position]);
            return theView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try putting in a ViewGroup layout such as a framelayout or relativelayout to surround the ListView (you said fragment xml only contains a listview).

Comment: Also, post LogCat if an error is occurring

Comment: I suspect the problem is with your adapter.

Comment: post adapter code. and if you are using BaseAdapter make sure `getCount()` is returning the size of your data.

Comment: I added my adapter code. It extends ArrayAdapter

Comment: @LucasCrawford, the listview is in a linear layout.

Comment: in the getView() of your adapter  remove this line  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater(); and replace it with  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

see if that helps Plus the count for the listview is also missing

Comment: @SagarDevanga, Changed it. Still isn't working. I do not think the issue is with the adapter though. Thanks

Comment: So you changed the LayoutInflater line right ?? Did you override the count function of the adapter

Comment: @SagarDevanga, no i didn't override the count function. I extended the arrayadapter

Comment: @bharat, I have posted the adapter code

Comment: But the array adapter need the count of the elements to be displayed.

Comment: @SagarDevanga, in my other adapter code for the nav drawer, i didnt override the count function there and it worked.

Comment: So I gave you the right answer in a way right. Please upvote the comment if it helped you

Comment: @SagarDevanga, I do not really know how to upvote your comment, can you please explain what i'm supposed to do? Your comment was helpful

Comment: Just hover over my comment that helped you . ON the left hand side you can see two grey icons click on the upward arrow

Comment: @SagarDevanga, i can not see any two grey icons. I may not be eligible to upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FeaturedAdapterListNav` calss constuctor

write this (need to inform adapter about your data set size)

```
super(context, R.layout.featured_each_row, title);
```

instead of

```
 super(context, R.layout.featured_each_row);
```

Comment: Thanks but after doing that it showed this -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class

Comment: if you are extending `ListActivity` | `ListFragment` you must set your `Listview` view id to `androi.R.id.list`

Comment: Okay. Let me check that, Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @bharat. Extended fragment and set the listview to the adapter. Thanks Thanks Thanks!!!!